# youtube api. Check duplicate

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I try to get info about video

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + videoId + "&key="+ apiKey + "&part=status",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log (textStatus, + ' | ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

I got the status - rejectionReason: "duplicate". 
How to get origin video id?

Answer (score 0):

That should be normal if the video has been rejected because of the reason of duplicated.

Comment: That's right. I need to get origin video id.

Comment: @Andrew glad to hear that! Anyway if I was helpful, you could vote my answer as best answer.